# SQLite3 Python - column not updating after second function call (Beginner programmer)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

First i'll explain how my code will be run.
`mainpythonfile.py` has only a few lines of code which imports and call another module and after that module is complete another module will be called and so forth.

After I call my first module, it runs as expected by UPDATE totalscore column with the associated id.

Code:

```
#starships.py
import level1

level1.levelOne(map)
```

Heading to level one module (everything is good here)

```
#level1.py
import RandomLocation
import sqlcreatetable
import InitMap
import level2
import time

def levelOne(map):
    sqlcreatetable.create_table()
    sqlcreatetable.user_entry()
    if sel_row == stship_row and sel_col == stship_col:
            InitMap.spawn_rows(map)
            sqlcreatetable.update()

            map[guess_row][guess_col] == "D"
            print "Congratulations! You Destroyed the enemy's corvette!"

            print "Name: ", 
            sqlcreatetable.read_name()

            print "Score: ", 
            sqlcreatetable.read_score()

            advanceLevel = raw_input("Advance to next level? ('y' or 'n') :")

            if advanceLevel == "y" or advanceLevel == "Y":
                level2.levelTwo(map)
```

The map spawns and table is now updated in db

```
#level2.py
import RandomLocation
import sqlcreatetable
from sqlcreatetable import tscore
import InitMap2
import level3
import time

def levelTwo(map):
sqlcreatetable.create_table()
sqlcreatetable.user_entry()
if sel_row == stship_row and sel_col == stship_col:
        InitMap.spawn_rows(map)
        sqlcreatetable.update()

        map[guess_row][guess_col] == "D"
        print "Congratulations! You Destroyed the enemy's corvette!"

        print "Name: ", 
        sqlcreatetable.read_name()

        print "Score: ", 
        sqlcreatetable.read_score()

        advanceLevel = raw_input("Advance to next level? ('y' or 'n') :")

        if advanceLevel == "y" or advanceLevel == "Y":
            level3.levelThree(map)
```

Here is where everything stops updating

SQL

```
#sqlcreatetable.py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('playerscores.db')
c = conn.cursor()

Name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
tscore = 0

def create_table():
    c.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE, totalscore INTEGER);"""
        )

def user_entry():
    c.execute(
        """INSERT INTO scores VALUES (NULL,?,NULL)""", (Name,)
        )
    conn.commit()

def update():
    c.execute(
        """SELECT totalscore FROM scores"""
    )

    c.execute(
        """UPDATE scores 
            SET totalscore = ? + 1
            WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM scores)""", (str(tscore))
        )
    conn.commit()

def read_score():
    c.execute(
    """SELECT totalscore FROM scores WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM scores);"""
        )   
    get_score = c.fetchone()
    print get_score
```

Please note that these are not the entire code but just parts of code.

Also any advice on how to improve my database (which collects names and scores of those names) would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why do you have three " delimiting the query strings? Try " instead of """

Comment: can you explain why this would be a problem? """ is multi-line commenting which allowed me to move to a next line or does this not apply when writing SQL code?

EDIT:
this dosent work, multi line comment needed

Comment: Well, I'm curious about why do you comment out the commands?

Comment: because in python, you need to comment the commands so python can read the sql (according to my knowledge) im a beginner programmer

Answer (score 0):

### POSSIBLE SOLUTION FOUND

ok so basically what i did was create a new `update_function()` in `sqlcreatetable.py` then instead of adding `+1` to `tscore` variable, i added `+2` since `score = score+1` everytime the the `statement` is `True`

```
def update_2():
    c.execute(
        """SELECT totalscore FROM scores"""
    )
    c.execute(
        """UPDATE scores 
            SET totalscore = ? + 2
            WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM scores)""", (str(tscore))
        )
```

but i dont think i would want to be creating multiple functions to achieve the same task